# What am I doing wrong to display links in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function DisplayDashboard(Work Package)
{
var Src = '';

if (Work Package=='Google')
{
    Src =<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>;
}
else if(Work Package=='Bing') 
{
    Src = <a href ="https://www.bing.com">Link</a>;
}
    return <'+Work Package+'>;
}   
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is to look for Google or Bing and then display the correct link in Javascript. But for some reason it is not working.

Comment: What's your HTML code, and is this all of your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Variable name `Work Package` cannot have space between the characters
2. `string` values must be surrounded bye `''` or `""`
3. You need to return the value of `Src`

Try

```
function DisplayDashboard(WorkPackage) {
    var Src = '';

    if (WorkPackage == 'Google') {
        Src = '<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>';
    } else if (WorkPackage == 'Bing') {
        Src = '<a href ="https://www.bing.com">Link</a>';
    }
    return Src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `Work Package` with `WorkPackage` .Remove space.

```
function DisplayDashboard(WorkPackage)
{
var Src = '';

if (WorkPackage=='Google') 
    Src ='<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>';   
else if(WorkPackage=='Bing')    
    Src = '<a href ="https://www.bing.com">Link</a>';   
    return src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to wrap HTML in double-quotes to form a valid string?

Such as:

```
Src = "<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>";
```